# Calculation on binding in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat and have a array of object.

So according to one of the parameter I want to resize image.

Duration contains time in milliseconds. I want to change it in minutes and set it as pixel

```
style="width:{{albumItem.duration}}
```

Comment: Please share your script

Comment: i dnt thing sharing script will help...i want to change on front end and not on javascript/angular side

Comment: what you doing is nothing but JavaScript and angular part. You can convert time to mins on fly in your controller. The code which you share is working code.What problem are you facing is not clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
ng-style="{{setWidth(albumItem.duration)}}"
```

Controller:-

```
    $scope.setWidth=function(millis){
     var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
    return{
        "width":minutes+"px"
      }
    }
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QEiosFbSJ0cw1PXm6B4h)** 
Hope it help :)